# mysql_query error if single quotes used

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I want to know why

```
$amzius_sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `Age` , SUBSTRING( Age, LOCATE( ' ', Age ) ) AS `AgePrefix` , SUBSTRING_INDEX( Age, ' ', 1 ) AS `AgeValue` FROM `suoPage` ORDER BY `AgePrefix` , `AgeValue` LIMIT 0 , 30";
$amzius_res = mysql_query($amzius_sql);
```

works flawlessly and this:

```
$amzius_sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT `Age` , SUBSTRING( Age, LOCATE( " ", Age ) ) AS `AgePrefix` , SUBSTRING_INDEX( Age, " ", 1 ) AS `AgeValue` FROM `suoPage` ORDER BY `AgePrefix` , `AgeValue` LIMIT 0 , 30';
$amzius_res = mysql_query($amzius_sql);
```

produces an error:
**Unknown column ' ' in 'field list'**

The only difference is quotes. If both queries are queried in phpMyAdmin - both work, but only the first one works if queried by mysql_query() in PHP

Comment: That's double-quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: You probbaly have [`ANSI_QUOTES` set to `ON`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes)

Comment: You can read more in the [String Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-literals.html) page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the explaination:

> The ANSI_QUOTES mode causes the server to interpret double-quoted
>   strings as identifiers. Consequently, when this mode is enabled,
>   string literals must be enclosed within single quotation marks. They
>   cannot be enclosed within double quotation marks.

[Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)